# tabela css em php dentro do div

Tags: php

Estou com um problema no php porque a div corta o texto da minha tabela.

```
 echo' <div class="tabla7">
 <p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div  class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
 <div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


<p>
<div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
<div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento"].'</div>
<div class="columna7">' .(date('Y/m/d') - $exibe["DataNascimento"] ).'</div>
<div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
<div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7">';if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
                echo '<span style="color:red">' . $exibe['MedicaValidade'] . '</span>';}
                else
               { echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];  }

               '</div>
  <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Documentos </a></div>
  </div>


<p><br><br>';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma forma muito estranha de fazer uma tabela. De qualquer forma tu fechas o teu `echo` antes do `if`. Depois do `{ echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];  }` tens de fazer de novo `echo '</div> ...`.

Comment: não consegui inserir tabelas dentro de divs e arranjei essa forma.

Comment: resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que tu fechas o teu `echo` antes do `if`. Depois do `{ echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];  }` tens de fazer de novo `echo '</div>`.

O teu código corrigido:

```
 echo' <div class="tabla7">
     <p><div class="titulo7">Nome</div><div class="titulo7">Data Nascimento</div><div  class="titulo7">Idade</div><div class="titulo7">Categoria Profissional</div>
     <div class="titulo7">Data Entrega EPIS</div><div class="titulo7">Validade FAM</div><div class="titulo7">Credenciais</div></p>


    <p>
    <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
    <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento"].'</div>
    <div class="columna7">' .(date('Y/m/d') - $exibe["DataNascimento"] ).'</div>
    <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
    <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
     <div class="columna7">';if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
                    echo '<span style="color:red">' . $exibe['MedicaValidade'] . '</span>';}
                    else
                   { echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];  }

                   echo '</div>
      <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Documentos </a></div>
      </div>


    <p><br><br>';
```

Comment: outra duvida que deve ser simples. tá a ver a imagem que coloquei? é possivel colocar as letras no centro?

Comment: No CSS: `.columna7{ vertical-align:middle; }`